# Strange AngularJS behavior, values not updating in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some issues in my application where I'm using `setInterval` to poll my server every X seconds to check for new messages, when it finds them it adds them to the SQLite database on the application and updates the Object containing the data for displacement on the screen.

The issue is that the values don't update automatically, as you can see in an example provided through this snippet below. Just click the button and you'll notice really quickly t hat nothing is happening in either the `ng-repeat` or just the standard `{{variable}}` display.

Click the button again and all of a sudden you have some results, but they're inconsistent and explosive.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.console = "";
    $scope.arr = [];

    $scope.init = function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $scope.arr.push("Value");
      }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.start = function() {
      alert("Started");
      $scope.init();
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <button ng-click="start()">Start Example</button>
  <br>

  <h5>For each:</h5>

  <div id="repeat-container" ng-repeat="x in arr">
    Value index: {{$index}}
    <br>
  </div>

  <hr>Updating value of array: {{arr}}

  <hr>

  <h5>Console:</h5>
  {{console}}

  <div>
```

I'm personally working with `ng-repeat` trying to get these values to display properly when updated through `setInterval`. There's a custom debug console I added in there, considering `console.log` doesn't show anything on snippets (Unless it's in the debug window, which I haven't checked, because I'm an idiot).

Why aren't they updating? Usually Angular does a really good job at keeping everything on the page updated and in sync with the values in the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `setInterval` creates events that angular does not monitor, so use the use the angular equivalent, `$timeout`, instead as this triggers a digest cycle. You may need to put the `$timeout` in a separate function to that it can call itself repeatedly to give you the equivalent of `setInterval`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.console = "";
    $scope.arr = [];

    $scope.init = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.arr.push("Value");
      }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.start = function() {
      alert("Started");
      $scope.init();
    };
  });
```

Comment: Your answer triggered my interest, and I found `$interval` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Great stuff. $interval is what you need. I'd just forgotten about it

Comment: I'm marking this correct, as it explained what the issue was, and provided a solution. If you would like to edit it containing information about `$interval` for future viewers, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `Angulars $interval service`. 
I think common-js setInterval don't gets the right `$scope?!`

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.console = "";
    $scope.arr = [];

    $scope.init = function() {
      $interval(function() {
        $scope.arr.push("Value");
      }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.start = function() {
      alert("Started");
      $scope.init();
    };
  });
```

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval):

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout and setInterval causes the scope releases update state free. What you're looking for is `$scope. $apply()` or `$interval ()` and `$timeout ()` functions of angular..